# How to change the style of a nested control in tornadofx

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

A textarea in JavaFx can have a background color assigned in css:

```
.text-area .content {
-fx-background-color: blue ;
}
```

How do I do this in tornadoFx within a style declaration ?

```
  override val root = gridpane {

    orderTextArea = textarea {
        isEditable = false
        prefWidth = 900.0
        prefHeight = 700.0
        isWrapText = true
        //textProperty().bind(viewModel.orderText)
        style {
            textFill = Color.YELLOW
            **//backgroundcolor**
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Create a stylesheet and describe the correct selector there
2. Locate the sub node and apply the style to it directly

No 2 is not recommended, because you have no guarantee for when the control actually instantiates that sub node. TornadoFX has two ways of doing no 1.

You can create a type safe stylesheet and add the reference to it to your app class. The stylesheet would look like this:

```
class Styles : Stylesheet() {
    init {
        textArea {
            content {
                backgroundColor += Color.BLUE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, there is another option in TornadoFX, and that is to create an inline stylesheet. This is not an inline style, but a complete stylesheet that will only be applied to the node you define it on (and it's sub nodes of course)

```
textarea {
    prefWidth = 900.0
    prefHeight = 700.0
    stylesheet {
        Stylesheet.content {
            backgroundColor += Color.BLUE
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you need to reference the defined CSS classes in Stylesheet.

Creating an external type safe stylesheet is always the best option.

Comment: The stylesheet class option is not possible if you use tornadoFx in a JavaFx legacy app (not derived from TornadoFx.App), is it ? I've not found a way to register the stylesheet class in this case

Comment: You should be able to call FX.importStylesheet()

Comment: hm...maybe I overlook sth but how do I get an instance of FX ? I have access to the companion object but the importStylesheet function is not static...the styleSheet property is accessible and I've copied the importStylesheet function to register a dsl based stylesheet but that did not work (stylesheet was ignored during runtime)